# Functors adjoint from both sides

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

If F is left adjoint to G and G is left adjoint to F, does it imply anything nice about these functors?

Comment: It implies they are both exact and continuous/co-continuous.

Comment: If $F\dashv G\dashv F$ you are dealing with a Frobenius functor http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+functor An immediate consequence of this is that $GF\dashv FG$.

Comment: It's also called an [ambidextrous adjunction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ambidextrous+adjunction) or an [ambijunction](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502550).